# click on Button using AppleScript/JavaScript without ID,Name,Class

Tags: javascript, button, click, applescript

I want want to click on this Button using AppleScript: But I don't know how to reach this Button in JavaScript, since it hasn't any id, name or class:

is it somehow possible to click on this button?

The Parten has an ID, but I still cannot click on it using this script.

```
to clickID(theId)
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();"       in document 1

end tell
end clickID

clickID("searchbutton")



[The Button I'm talking about][1]
this ist the site: [here][2] 
it's the big "Suche starten >>" Button
```

Comment: The button's parent has an ID...

Comment: what is the id of the buttons's parent? I can't see it? where is it? And how can I access my button then? You mean "searchbutton" ?... but somehow my script isn't working with this ID

Answer (score 0):

The element ID "searchbutton" is a **div**, the input ("**Suche starten**" button) is within this **div**.

The script need to get the first child element of this div, so you can use `.firstElementChild` or `.children[0]`, like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('searchbutton').firstElementChild.click()" in document 1
end tell
```